# Asynccallback with in for loop

Tags: java, asynchronous, gwt

I am new in GWT, So please help me.  I have on for loop n times loop; every loop sent the `AsyncCallback` to server and fetch the value. but I want to stop every loop until server response. for example

```
for (final String cardId : cardIds) {
    cmain.ivClient.getm(cardId, cardInfoKeys, new AsyncCallback<String[]>() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String[] result) {
            cardPar = result;
        }
    }
}
```

How to wait the loop for every time?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please properly format your code next time, it was very hard to read. You can prepend 4 spaces or select the code and click the `{}` button in the toolbar. Always take a look at the preview displayed below your post before submitting, to see whether it looks OK. Also, it's not very clear to me what you are asking. What did you try already, how did it fail?

Comment: Why not just send all `cardIds` in one go?

Comment: Please remember to mark answers as accepted, as this tells other people coming to see this question that one of the solutions worked in your case. You seem to have asked several questions that got upvoted answers (by other members), but you never marked them as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you cannot really use the for loop in this case.

If you know, there will be, say, 3 calls, you can stack the async calls: 
In each `onSuccess()` you fire the next async call.

If you do not know how many there will be, you can recurse over the `onSuccess` call.

```
void callServer(final List<String>cardIds) {
    if(cardIds.isEmpty()) return;

    cmain.ivClient.getm(cardId, cardInfoKeys, new AsyncCallback<String[]>() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String[] result) {
            doImportantMatterWith( result );
            cardIds.remove(0);
            callServer(cardIds);
        }
    }
}
```

This is rather ugly, but will make sure, that the next call will only be fired, when the previous returned successful.

I suggest to not implement this async call chaining, but rather request all results from the server at once.